# Multidimensional Array Printing Gives Something Different

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

int x[5][5] = {{0,1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8,9}};

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", x[i][j]); } }

return 0; }
```

This was supposed to give me: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

And the result is: 0 5 0 0

And then, when I change them to chars:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

char x[5][5] = {{'0','1','2','3','4'},{'5','6','7','8','9'}};

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", x[i][j]); } }

return 0; }
```

I get 48 53 0  0.

Why? The code is pretty clear for me, but it seems that is happening something obscure on background (Or my brain works in a very "pythonic" way...)

Comment: Well, first of all, you have two sets of five numbers and three sets of five zeroes. I don't know if that's what you were going for.

Comment: In C '0', '1'... are characters with numeric values 48, 49...

Comment: @suspectus, Not necessarily. It can change depending on which character set is in use.

Comment: Why do you expect 10 numbers to be printed with a loop that executes 5×5=25 times?

Comment: The declaration `int x[5][5] = {{0,1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8,9}};` declares a 5 by 5 array of `int`s, but only *explicitly* initializes 10 `int` elements. The remaining 15 `int` elements are implicitly initialized to zero.

Comment: why are you using the same index i in both the loops?

Comment: And why are you testing `< 4` when it should be `< 5`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like @Keith Thompson said, you didn't initialize all 25 elements. So the remaining elements are initialized to `0`. As a result, the data will be stored this way:

```
  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4     // Row 0
  5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9     // Row 1
  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0     // Row 2
  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0     // Row 3
  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0     // Row 4
```

You only initialized the first two rows of your array. This is the reason why you got `0 5 0 0` as your output.

To get the correct output, you need to loop through the first two rows of your array.

## Steps to fix this :

**First**

You need to change your first for-loop from:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
```

Reason: Because you only want to loop through the first two rows *(row 0 and row 1)*.

**Second**

You need to change your second for-loop from:

```
for (int j = 0; i < 4; i++)
```

to:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
```

Reason: You need variable `j` for your loop condition, not `i`. You also need to change from `4` to `5`; because in an array, the index starts with 0. So, the indexes of each columns are `0,1,2,3,4` , respectively.

## To sum up, your code supposed to be...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
    {
        printf("%d\n", x[i][j]); 
    } 
}
```

Additionally, when you are changing to `char x[5][5]`, you need to use `%c`, to print a character, instead of  `%d`.

Moreover, the reason you are getting weird numbers like `48` because when you print a `char` with `%d`, you are actually printing its [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) values. Referring to the ASCII table below, number `48` represents character `'0'`.

[image: http://www.asciitable.com/]
Image from http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Yes, the array is 5 by 5, because he defined it that way. Here merely didn't *explicitly* initialize all 25 elements; the remaining 15 elements are implicitly initialized to 0.

Comment: Just a quick note that C doesn't require ASCII as the character set; Some implementations use [EBCDIC](http://ferretronix.com/march/computer_cards/ebcdic_table.jpg), instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
for(j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++)
printf("%d\n",x[i][j]);
```

i dont know why you initialized only 2 1-d arrays. but changing the bounds in the for loop should suffice your needs